# How to get a numpy array from values of another array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have the array

```
[[ 430  780 1900  420][ 0 0 2272 1704]]
```

and needs to convert it into this result:

```
[[[ 430  780 1] [1900  420 1]] [[ 0  0 1] [2272  1704 1]]]
```

basically turn a 2d array into 3d, separate each array into 2 and append the number 1 to it. How can I achieve it?

Comment: That largely depends on your criteria for splitting. Based on your desired output you are splitting into halved arrays, what should the output be for odd number of items in the array? Should the odd item be in the first array or the second? Or is this just a very specific case and doesn't need to generalize? Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the question leaves some ambiguity about what would happen with bigger arrays, but one way to obtain the result that you indicate is this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[430, 780, 1900, 420], [0, 0, 2272, 1704]])
b = a.reshape(a.shape[0], -1, 2)
b = np.concatenate([b, np.ones_like(b[..., -1:])], -1)
print(b)
# [[[ 430  780    1]
#   [1900  420    1]]
# 
#  [[   0    0    1]
#   [2272 1704    1]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, for small size arrays(for large arrays consider @jdehesa answer).

```
>>> arr = [[ 430, 780, 1900, 420],[ 0, 0, 2272, 1704]]

>>> [[[a[0],a[1],1],[a[2],a[3],1]] for a in arr]

[[[430, 780, 1], [1900, 420, 1]], [[0, 0, 1], [2272, 1704, 1]]]
```